# How to design php class with properties that can only be set once

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, abstract-class, subclass

I'm writing a "parent" class that is meant to be extended. I want the extenders to set a handful of properties once when they define the class but I don't want those values to ever change after they've been initially set. What's the correct way to do this?

Update:

To clarify, I want the property to act as a constant that the extending class sets once but can't modify afterwards. For this reason I can't simply make it a private property with a getter method. The extending class could just add a setter, right?

Comment: See [Visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php), especially `private`, on how to prevent members to be changed by someone else.

Comment: Make `protected` to those properties in parent class, and in child take these properties in constructor, and only create getter method for them. One other way is to try Factory Design Pattern

Answer (score 5):

You set the variables you dont want to be writable as `private` and then don't provide any mutators for them to the child classes, e.g.

```
abstract class Foo 
{    
    private $value;    

    public function __construct($value) 
    {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    protected function getValue() 
    {
        return $this->value;
    }
}
```

Depending on what `$value` is, you might need to `clone` it before returning it to the child class.

In your child class, you'd do

```
class Bar extends Foo 
{
    public function someMethodUsingValue()
    {
        $value = $this->getValue();
        // do something with $value
    }
}

$bar = new Bar(42);
$bar->someMethodUsingValue();
```

Because `$value` is private, Bar can only access it through the provided Getter of Foo, but cannot access it directly. This prevents Bar from changing it (as long as it's not an object of course, see note above about cloning).

If your child class needs a different constructor than the parent, you need to make sure it actually invokes the parent constructor with the to be immutable values, e.g. in Bar

```
public function __construct($value, $something)
{
    parent::__construct($value);
    $this->something = $something;
}
```

Also see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

---

Yet another (and preferable) option would be to encapsulate the immutable value(s) in one or several classes and aggregate/compose them within the parent classes, instead of inheriting them:

```
class Bar
{
    private $data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->data = new ImmutableValue(42);
    }

    public function getValue()
    {
        return $this->data->getValue();
    }
}

class ImmutableValue
{
    private $value;

    public function __construct($value)
    {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function getValue()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }
}
```

As you can see, this one does not use inheritance. It's not needed. Refer to the following two articles for more details:

- https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/composition-vs-inheritance-how-choose
- http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html

---

Since you mention constants in your question, you can obviously achieve the whole thing without using inheritance or composition and just set a real constant, e.g.

```
class Bar
{
    const VALUE = 42;
}

echo Bar::VALUE; // 42
```

or use a constant method:

```
class Bar
{
    public final function getValue() 
    {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

Making the getter `final` prevents any subclass from modifying the method.

---

Regarding your comments:

> What would happen if Bar added a method like setMyProperty($value)? Will $this->myProperty be indefinite because it's private?

You would end up with a new public property set in the Bar instance with the same name. But the private instance var of the parent would be left unchanged.

```
class Foo 
{
    private $value = 1;
}

class Bar extends Foo 
{
    public function setValue($value)
    {
        $this->value = $value;
    }
}

$bar = new Bar;
$bar->setValue(42);
var_dump($bar);
```

Would give you

```
object(Bar)#1 (2) {
  ["value:private"]=>
  int(1)
  ["value"]=>
  int(42)
}
```

So no, the extending class could not just add a setter. Private is private.

---

> Also, is there a way to do this without passing the variables through the constructor? I'd like those attributes to be defined in the inherited class […]

You could utilize the pattern shown elsewhere on this page, where you add a setter method that allows setting only once and then raises an exception on subsequent calls. However, I don't like that since it's really what a constructor is for. And I don't see the issue with passing the variables through the constructor. Consider this:

```
public function __construct($somethingElse)
{
    parent::__construct(42);
    $this->somethingElse = $somethingElse;
}
```

This way, `$value` is set from the constructor in the inherited class. There is no way to change it from the outside, nor from within Bar. And no additional logic required in some sort of setter.

> […] so they're version controlled.

I am not sure you really mean version controlled. If you want version control, utilize a proper system for that, e.g. git or mercurial or any other widely available VCS.

---

On a side note: there is an [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/immutability), that aims to add Immutable classes and properties as a native language feature. However, it's still in Draft as of today.

Comment: But what stops the extending class form adding a setter method to modify the value later?

Comment: @emerson the private visibility prevents it

Comment: What would happen if `Bar` added a method like setMyProperty($value)? Will $this->myProperty be indefinite because it's private?

Comment: Also, is there a way to do this without passing the variables through the constructor? I'd like those attributes to be defined in the inherited class so they're version controlled.

Comment: @emersonthis I have updated the answer to address your comments

Comment: I am using git for version control. The long was that I wanted those values to exist on the class  definition somehow. So that someone looking at the class would know those values without having to see an example of it being instantiated for it to make sense

Comment: @emersonthis added some more options. I think this covers most cases now.

Answer (score 3):

Declare the property as private and set it via a protected setter. In this setter you can do your control

```
abstract class YourClass {
   private $myProperty;

   protected function setMyProperty($value) {
        if(is_null($this->myProperty)) {
             $this->myProperty = $value;
        }else {
             throw new Exception("You can set this property only once");
        }
   }

   protected function getMyProperty() {
          return $this->myProperty;
   }
}
```

In order to fetch the property you need also a protected getter (or public if you need to have access from external).

Another point of view:

There is a common rule in OOP: [prefer composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Try to think a different approach: if you need a set of immutable properties, you can encapsulate them in an object, then use this object as component.

```
class MyClass {
    /**
     * @var MyComponent
     */
    protected $component;

    public function __construct($property) {
        $this->setComponent(new MyComponent($property));
    }

    protected function setComponent(MyComponent $myComponentInstance) {
        $this->component = $myComponentInstance;
    }

    public function doSomething() {
        echo $this->component->getMyProperty();
    }
}

class MyComponent {
    private $myProperty;

    public function __construct($property) {
        $this->myProperty = $property;
    }
    public function getMyProperty() {
        return $this->myProperty;
    }

}

$myClass = new MyClass("Hello World");

$myClass->doSomething();
```

EDIT:

Reading your edit, I think you want this:

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass {
    const FOO = 1;

    public function getFoo() {
        // hint: use "static" instead of "self"
        return static::FOO;
    }
}

class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass{
    // override
    const FOO = 2;
}

$myClass = new MyClass();

echo $myClass->getFoo(); // 2
```

Comment: Great answer. I'm considering the object storage method. I can definitely see how that would be really useful in real-world projects. My use-case is more of a game / teaching exercise that I'm trying to keep as simple as possible. Is there a way to do the private variable method without passing the values into the constructor? I want those values to be a part of the subclass.

Comment: @emersonthis you can define a "configure" method for your component class. And/or use an hardcoded property used by "MyClass". Using `new MyComponent("Hello World");`, or $myComponent->configure(["property"=>"Hello World"]);

Comment: the value overridden of the constant FOO (2 in this case)